# Create CRUD Powerapps using Own API without Azure?

Tags: rest, api, azure, crud, powerapps

I am new with powerapps, I want to create CRUD operation and use my own api with powerapps, how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose your API in PowerApps, for both CRUD operations and for “regular” API operations, using a Custom Connector.

With this connector you can then consume that API from PowerApps. You can find more details about creating such custom connector at https://powerapps.microsoft.com/tutorials/register-custom-api/.

You can follow the "Create a custom connector from scratch" section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank for CRUD operation with your custom connector.

And follow section "Use a custom connector from a PowerApps app" to apply your custom connector to Power Apps. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-powerapps)